# Django and weasyprint, merge pdf

Tags: python, django, pdf, weasyprint

It's possible to merge multiple pdf in django with weasyprint?

I have something like this:

```
def verpdf(request, pk):
    odet = get_object_or_404(Note, pk = pk)
    template = get_template('pdfnot.html')
    template1 = get_template('pdfnot2.html')
    p1 = template.render({'odet': odet}).encode(encoding="ISO-8859-1")
    p2 = template1.render({'note':odet}).encode(encoding="ISO-8859-1")
    pdf1 = HTML(string=p1).render()
    pdf2 = HTML(string=p2).render()
    all_pages = [po for po in pdf1.pages for doc in pdf2.pages]
    pdf_file = pdf1.copy(all_pages).write_pdf()
    http_response = HttpResponse(pdf_file, content_type='application/pdf')
    http_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="report.pdf"'

    return http_response
```

But i'm not able to join the two files, always output only the first template, it's possible to merge the two documents into one pdf? Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Took me a while, but i solved it, was my fault for not understand the documentation lol, here is the code if anyone have the same problem:

```
def verpdf(request, pk):
    odet = get_object_or_404(Note, pk = pk)
    template = get_template('pdfnot.html')
    template1 = get_template('pdfnot2.html')
    p1 = template.render({'odet': odet}).encode(encoding="ISO-8859-1")
    p2 = template1.render({'note':odet}).encode(encoding="ISO-8859-1")
    pdf1 = HTML(string=p1)
    pdf2 = HTML(string=p2)
    pdf11 = pdf1.render()
    pdf12 = pdf2.render()

    val = []

    for doc in pdf11, pdf12:
        for p in doc.pages:
            val.append(p)

    pdf_file = pdf11.copy(val).write_pdf() # use metadata of pdf11

    http_response = HttpResponse(pdf_file, content_type='application/pdf')
    http_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="report.pdf"'

    return http_response
```

And with this an pdf output with two pages.

Comment: more details here: [weasyprint documentation: tips & tricks](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips-tricks.html#include-header-and-footer-of-arbitrary-complexity-in-a-pdf)

Answer (score 1):

`<p style="page-break-before: always"></p>` after the body tag is an option as well